# How can I show a fixed after scroll but hide it if the screen is smaller than

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add a fixed div on the top after the user scrolls down but how can I hide that same div if the resized window is smaller than 768px and show it back again if the window is bigger than 769px?

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
          var y = $(this).scrollTop();
          if (y > 400) {
            $('.js-quick-navbar').show();
          } else if($(this).width() < 768) {
            $('.js-quick-navbar').hide();
          }
});
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brunodd/qefoLdwa/6/)**

Comment: ever heard of `window.onscroll` event?? And I wonder why do you even need javascript to do that when **css is more than enough**?

Comment: I tried css but it won't hide the div as it's being called through jQuery. But please if you think css is enough then show me on fiddle.

Comment: why is being called through javascript?

Comment: there must be some inline styles that cause this

Comment: is being called through javascript because I need to show that div after the user scrolls.

Comment: my friend you can add class instead of show or hide and let the class show or hide it for you.. That'd be the optimal approach

Comment: Thank you. Can you show us, please? Where is your fiddle?

Comment: try creating a .hidden {display: none;} .visible {display: block} classes in css and add these classes and then use media queries to make the div fixed

Comment: I've answered below. PS.: you can remove the class`visible` if you need and get rid of that `!important` as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's just a matter of showing or hiding a div based on the window width, then you could use Media queries.

```
@media (max-width:768px){
  .quick-navbar {
      display:none;
    }
  }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/daveSalomon/qefoLdwa/7/

However, if you need to support browsers which don't support CSS media queries (yuck!), then you could use jQuery, and listen on `window.resize`.
It's worth looking into `throttling`, and also optimising the following. For example, `.show()` will be called regardless of whether or not it is necessary. It'll also fire an event for every `px` the window is resized - you really want to batch them together and action it every *x* seconds. (Great post: http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/)

```
$(window).resize(function(){
  var w = $(this).width();
  if(w > 768){
      $('.quick-navbar').show();
  } else {
      $('.quick-navbar').hide();
  }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/daveSalomon/qefoLdwa/8/

Missed the scroll part - apologies.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){ ... });
if(w > 768 && $(window).scrollTop() > 200){ ... }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/daveSalomon/qefoLdwa/9/

Comment: What about the scroll function? I need to show the div if the user scrolls down. But that same div should be hidden if the window is < 768

Answer (score 0):

**CSS**

```
.hidden {
    display: hidden;
}
.visible {
    display: block;
}

@media (max-width:768px){
  .js-quick-navbar {
      display:none !important; // Added important since we may have the .visible class attached to it at times
    }
  }
}
```

**JS**

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (y > 400) {
        $('.js-quick-navbar').addClass('visible');
    } else if($(this).width() < 768) {
        $('.js-quick-navbar').addClass('hidden');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for trying to help but your example doesn't seem to be working. http://jsfiddle.net/brunodd/qefoLdwa/10/